# Which is the best way to monitor USB port with flex or flash?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, sockets, adobe, usb

I want to write an application that monitor the USB port, and when something is connected should show the contents of the drive (image viewer) automatically.

there is any way to do that with Flex/Flash directly?
or i might program another application in C in order to monitor the USB port and then comunicate with the front-end application with sockets?

Thanks
br.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is possible with the AIR SDK version 2. It is unfortunately still in beta but should be out soon. http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/air2/

Comment: +1 that's what I was going to recommend. AIR 2 supports that.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the answer(s) to this SO question helpful: [Talk to USB device and vice versa from Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541616/talk-to-usb-device-and-vice-versa-from-flex)

Comment: thanks. very interesting project, anyway i assume that due security restrictions there is no way to access directly the hw either in flash or AIR applications. i'll take a look of this libraries, but i am not good with java :-(

regards.